# MongoDb - Using a Hash Map to Reduce Index Size?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, hashmap

I have some project where I'm using two collections that need to reference each other:

`db_A` has a list like the following:

```
e_id: 12345678910,
other_data: text
```

Each `e_id` is unique and is a number anywhere between 8 and 11 digits.

`db_B` has a list like the following:

```
some_data: text,
e_ids: [array of e_id]
```

So it's a one-to-many relationship as shown, and we want to do things like pull a list of `e_ids` from `db_A` and see which entries of those match in `db_B`.

Problem is that `db_B` has millions of entries and each entry could have thousands of `e_ids`. `db_A` only has 300K or so entries.

I just tried indexing `db_B.e_ids` and it's almost half the size of the data in the collection, and over 10x the size of the RAM!

Would it be feasible to maintain some sort of hashmap where a smaller key references `e_id` to reduce the data size in index? e.g.:

`db_A`

```
e_id: 12345678910,
key: 1
other_data: text

e_id: 12345678911,
key: 2
other_data: text
```

`db_B`

```
some_data: text,
e_ids: [1, 2, ...] // instead of [12345678910, 12345678911, ...]
```

Would this even have an appreciable effect? What would be the best way to implement a hash-map like this, or is there a better solution altogether?